# Best approach in implementing both phone and email auth in firebase for a single use?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am developing a flutter application I want my user to login using both email and phone.
My intention is to first register the user using phone no and allow the user to add an email address and password and the user should be able to login using them and also via phone no and the password used for email auth.
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For both phone and Email based authentication using firebase is a good idea, as it supports both phone authentication and email authentication.

best way to use both is to create multiple auth pages
1) for accepting phone number and verifying it
2) for accepting email and setting up a password then verification by email.

then on the next screen set up a login method (use either email or phone number for authentication)

Comment: The problem is that then there will be two users right?

Comment: Not really since you just are using one method for creating the user (either email or phone), the only way there would be "duplicate users" is if they created an account with a phone number and another with an email.

Comment: @user10595057 have u got any solution?